# pyodbc fetchall() returns no results when a column returned by the query contains too much data

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

Setup:I am using Python 3.3 on a Windows 2012 client. 
I have a select query running using [pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) which is not returning any results via fetchall().  I know the query works fine because i can take it out and run it from Microsoft SQL Management Studio without any issues.
I can also remove one column from the select list and the query will return results.  For the database row in question, this column contains a large amount of XML data (> 10,000 characters), so it seems as though there is some buffer overflow issue going on causing fetchall() to fail, though it doesn't throw any exceptions.  I have tried googling around and i have seen rumors of a config option to raise the buffer size, but i haven't been able to nail down exactly how to do it, or what a workaround would be.

Is there a configuration option that I can use, or any alternative to pyodbc.

> Disclaimer: I have only been using python for about 2 weeks now so i
>   am still quite the noob, though i have made every attempt to research
>   my problems thoroughly this one has proven to be elusive:

On a side note, i tried using odbc instead of pyodbc but the same query throws this oddball error which google isn't helping me solve either

> [ERROR] An exception while executing the Select query: [][Negative size passed to PyBytes_FromStringAndSize]

Comment: What operating system and stack are you using? If on Linux, are you using FreeTDS / unixODBC with pyodbc?

Comment: I am on Windows 2012.  unsure what you mean by which stack.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Windows 7 64-bit with Python 3.4.1 and SQL Server Native Client 11.0. What ODBC driver and version are in use? Post the code that is producing the error.

Comment: well i didnt post anything specific because it seemed data specific. giving the query wouldn't help without the corresponding data in the database.  I am using SQL Server Native Client 11.0 in my connection string however. I will see if i can pick out some pieces to post in the origina question

Comment: I used the [AdventureWorks2008R2](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/59211) database, `Production.Illustration` table to try to reproduce. The `Diagram` column in that table contains XML-typed data greater than 10,000 characters. You may want to try reproducing the problem from that sample database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this issue was resolved by changing my SQL connection string

FROM:

```
DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}
```

TO:

```
DRIVER={SQL Server}
```